Which musical notes will be produced by a guitar minor chord sound uploaded as an audio file in the FL Studio piano roll?
Correct me if I'm wrong, If I upload the sound of a guitar C1 musical note as an audio file to FL Studio, in the piano roll I will have all the other musical notes for that guitar, for example if I press D1 I will have D1, if I press E1 I will have E1, etc.
What will happen if I upload a guitar minor chord sound, and then I press the keys C1, D1, E1, etc. Which musical notes / chords will I have?

If you map a C note to middle C on your keyboard, playing C, D, E will result in C,D,E.  Just like it was a normal keyboard.
If you map a C minor triad, you'll get THAT, shifted in the same way.


It seems like Edward's warnings about setting the root are important here

If you're sampling notes, yes, it makes sense to assign a C pitch to the C key.  Sampling chords will have less musical use, music isn't often about a string of same-shape chords at different pitches.  But sure, arrange it so that pressing C gives a C minor chord.  Or maybe an A minor one?

If you load the sound of a guitar C1 musical note into the FL studio sampler plugin (I assume this is what you mean), then when you play the MIDI note C5, it will sound C1.  For every semitone above or below C5, the sounding pitch will be raised or lowered a semitone (unless you have changed the stretch mode in the sampler to one that does not allow real-time timestretching).
FL studio does not know what pitch your sample is until you tell it by setting the correct root note- by right-clicking the sounding pitch in the plugin wrapper.  Only then will the MIDI note C1 sound C1.
For practical reasons, if you are loading, for example, an E minor chord into the sampler, you should set your root note to E.  Then C on your keyboard will sound C minor, D will sound D minor, and E will sound E minor.
Relevant manual pages:
Sampler
Plugin wrapper

When working with samples, a key of the keyboard is just a "button" that plays the sound. If the sample is dog barking, then depressing three keys will give you three simultaneous dog barks, pitch-shifted in proportion to the keys pressed.
So if the sample is a single note, then pressing three keys will create a chord. But if the sample is a chord, then pressing three keys will play three different copies of that chord simultaneously, pitch-shifted. So pressing C, D, and E would presumably give you a C chord, a D chord, and an E chord. Which will contain a lot of major 2nd and at least one minor 2nd, and sound pretty clustered.
